# Write to google compute instance using apache spark

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, apache-spark-2.0

I have a 4 node hadoop cluster with spark version 2.2.0 installed on it. I want to move files from my local cluster to google compute engine instance. Any idea how to do it using apache spark? Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options available to transfer files to Compute Engine instances [1].

This video [2] can help understand moving Spark and Hadoop workloads to GCP.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files

[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfxvjWSgplU

Comment: Thank you so much! The first link is great!